# PostgreSQL create database statement takes longer than usual

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Creating a new empty database (using pgAdmin 4) usually takes 5-15 sec but recently it started to take much longer (2-3min).

When creating a new database I use a template (postgis) database. We have recently switched from postgresql 9 to 10.

Anticipating potential questions:

- template database is empty (only template tables etc)
- I did the VACUUM FULL
- the database server (Win server 2012, Intel Xeon 3,2 Ghz 12 cores, 64GB RAM) is not very overloaded - on average: 7-10% CPU, 30-35% memory usage

Any hints what might be the reason? what elese should I check ?

Comment: "only template tables" - the standard Postgres template database does **not** contain any "template tables". What kind of tables are those? Did you create them yourself?

Comment: to be more specific - template database I use is a postgis database so it contains i.e. spatial_ref_sys table. But actually  I've noticed that it doesn't matter if I create database using postgis template, or any other (or no template) - it takes much longer in all cases..

Comment: See if the statement is CPU or I/O bound. That will give a clue.

Comment: when executing the statement the CPU is "20% and memory is @40%